# How to add multiple item using only one button?

Tags: php

I'm making a simple inventory system using PHP and MySQL.

Is it possible to add multiple items after clicking a button and save them into a database? Like adding 5 items with different stock no.

I can only add one item at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add additional input fields in your form for each item you want to add.  Each one will need a unique name (e.g. item_0, item_2, etc...). In your form handler, it should check which ones are not empty, and insert them.

If you need help implementing, post the code that you currently have.